# My servo wont turn when accepting commands from an arduino

Tags: arduino, servo, control

I'm trying to turn a servo with my arduino when it receives commands from a serial input, in this case my keyboard. I have already done this with motors and it works fine but when I try with my servo it doesn't move at all. So far I have this written

```
#include <SoftwareServo.h>

SoftwareServo myservo;
int movemotor;

void setup() {  
  Serial.begin(9600);
  myservo.attach (10);
  myservo.write(90);
}

void loop() {
  movemotor = Serial.read();

  if (movemotor = 111) {
     for (int pos = 90; pos >=0; pos--) {
       myservo.write(pos);
       delay(15);
    }
  }

  else if (movemotor = 99) {
     for (int pos = 90; pos <= 180; pos++) {
       myservo.write(pos);
       delay(15);
    }
  }
}
```

I'm powering the servo externally with a 9 volt battery and have made sure to connect its ground to that of the arduino but can't see anything else I did wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you add a photo of your setup? Also, this is probably unrelated, but "movemotor = 111" means "assign value of 111 to the variable movemotor", and evaluates as true. You were probably aiming for "movemotor == 111". Same goes for the second if.

Comment: Look at the output signal.  It should be a pulse from 1 to 2 ms in length repeating every 20-50 ms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried going through an [Arduino servo example/tutorial](http://arduino.cc/playground/Learning/SingleServoExample)? The linked example shows one thing you are missing: a call to [refresh()](http://arduino.cc/playground/ComponentLib/Servo)

> refresh()
>    You must call this at least once every 50ms to keep the
>   servos updated. You can call it as often as you like, it won't fire
>   more than once every 20ms. When it does fire, it will take from .5 to
>   2.5 milliseconds to complete, but won't disable interrupts.

Edit: as TheTerribleSwiftTomato mentioned, you are not checking the value of movemotor but setting it. Because of this, the first if statement should always be true as any non-zero value will evaluate to true. You can avoid these assignment condition errors by adopting the [Yoda condition](http://united-coders.com/christian-harms/what-are-yoda-conditions) style. It looks a bit funny, but helps the compiler catch errors for you.

Comment: Hmmm... the Servo library that I use (from the bog-standard Arduino IDE, looks to be the most recent version) doesn't require this call. In any case, the inquirer seems to use a different servomotor lib.

Comment: ...which does indeed need a call to refresh() . My bad.

Comment: Thanks for the help on this, I had initially included the call to refresh but took it out while playing around with the code and forgot to put it back in. I think the main problem was that I was setting the value to move motor rather than checking it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. You might also want to check that the pins you are attaching to the arduino and servo are correct; eg, voltage, ground, and pulse.

```
// Sweep
// by BARRAGAN <http://barraganstudio.com> 
// This example code is in the public domain.


#include <Servo.h> 

Servo myservo;  // create servo object to control a servo 
                // a maximum of eight servo objects can be created 

int pos = 0;    // variable to store the servo position 

void setup() 
{ 
  myservo.attach(9);  // attaches the servo on pin 9 to the servo object 
} 


void loop() 
{ 
  for(pos = 0; pos < 180; pos += 1)  // goes from 0 degrees to 180 degrees 
  {                                  // in steps of 1 degree 
    myservo.write(pos);              // tell servo to go to position in variable 'pos' 
    delay(15);                       // waits 15ms for the servo to reach the position 
  } 
  for(pos = 180; pos>=1; pos-=1)     // goes from 180 degrees to 0 degrees 
  {                                
    myservo.write(pos);              // tell servo to go to position in variable 'pos' 
    delay(15);                       // waits 15ms for the servo to reach the position 
  } 
}
```